# RewriteRule matches (.*), but not specific path

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Banging my head against the wall on this one. Url I'm working with http://example.com/test/somewhere

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{SERVER_NAME}/sample/somewhere-else [R=301,L]
```

Works fine, and routes all traffic out to example.com/sample/somewhere-else as to be expected

However...

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^test/somewhere$ http://%{SERVER_NAME}/sample/somewhere-else [R=301,L]
```

This doesn't seem to match and does nothing. Am I writing this very basic regular expression wrong?

Comment: You may need a leading slash, as  `^/test/somewhere$`

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately I attempted adding the / (along with other various variations in desperation) and I'm still in the same boat :(

Comment: Are you actually sending requests with `Host: example.com`?

Comment: Just verified my headers to be safe, and I am indeed sending requests as `Host: example.com`. The actual url I'm working with (just to be clear) is chickasawcountry.com/explore/stay and the Header is sending through `Host: chickasawcountry.com`

Comment: Do you have a directory named test?  That will definitely mess things up.

Comment: Do you have any other rules? Do other expressions beside `.*` work? For example `^/?foo$` or `^/?foo`?

Comment: @Jeff-Meadows This site is actually using an MVC framework so "test" is the class that is actually being called so there is no directory per say.

Comment: @Qtax I do have other rules in the .htaccess file, both above and below where this rule is taking place. You bring up a great question, however on if other expressions work besides .* I'll tinker around with it tonight and see if I can get ANYTHING to work :)

Comment: Other rules can be messing this up for you. Try removing them.